# Ubuntu goes back to reinstall screen after VM shutdown - using UTM

Tags: virtualization

So I installed ubuntu using UTM, and it works.
Thing is, every time I shut down the VM, it goes back to the installation screen,
essentially deleting everything I did.

Any idea what might be causing that?

Thanks!

Comment: What is UTM? Never heard of that with Ubuntu.

Comment: The description suggests that you have merely copied over the Ubuntu installer image (which contains a working environment) into your VM. You did not actually install Ubuntu.

Comment: Definitely installed it, it's probably an issue with the different boot order or something, but I couldn't find it. Anyway I found another solution (tart) that helps run macOS as well and works well

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu in UTM is booting to the Ubuntu installation media instead of booting to the OS that you installed. Remove the Ubuntu installation iso from the virtual drive in UTM.

Alternatively Tart provides a powerful command-line toolset with a basic GUI for building, running, and managing VMs on Apple Silicon Macs. Tart delivers smooth performance by tightly integrating with Apple's hardware and software.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it didn't work for me. Anyway I found another solution (tart) that helps run macOS as well and works well :)

Comment: @Guy.oxnb Please edit my answer with your solution and I will accept your edit.